# Command works in "Run" but not in "CMD" or "Call Shell"

Tags: vba, command-prompt

I have a .exe file I want to run with some parameters, when I open "Run" (windows+R) and type in the following:  `C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV0 Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR`, the program runs perfectly.

However if I try this same thing through CMD (ive tried `CMD` with `cmd /c`) or `Call Shell()` (I Ultimately need it to work in VBA Call Shell, it doesn't work.

Text Input in Run: `C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV_0.exe Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR`  - WORKS

Text Input in CMD: `C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV_0.exe Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR` -- DOESN'T WORK

Text Input in CMD: `cmd /c C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV_0.exe Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR` -- DOESN'T WORK

Call Shell Command: `Call Shell("C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV_0.exe Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR")` -- DOESN'T WORK

There are no errors in CMD or in Call Shell, the cursor shows a loading icon for some time and then it stops, nothing happens, ideally at the end of the execution of my program a PDF should be created and opened

Im completely confused by this...

Comment: ① I see no exe file in `C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV0 Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR` if there is one, then call it correctly (including the `.exe`). ② Please show *how* you tried this in CMD and VBA `Shell()` command. Also *"doesn't work"* is no error description. Tell us what happens or which error you get.

Comment: Sorry about that i edited it

Comment: How many parameters do you expect this to be? I count 6 parameters. Also you still did not eplain what *"doesn't work"* means. Which error do you get? What happens?

Comment: yes there are 6 parameters, unfortunately there are no errors, the cursor just shows a loading icon and then it stops, ideally at the end of execution of my .exe a PDF gets created at a path and then opens, in the case of DOESNT WORK, the PDF doesnt get created nor opens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. This should work. Your issues looks to be somewhere else or in your exe file:

I tested with the following code

```
Sub test()
    Call Shell("D:\temp\test.bat Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

and the following `test.bat` to list the parameters:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)

echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"

pause
```

The outcome is this:

[image]

If you have any spaces in your path make sure to surround it by quotes like below:

```
Call Shell("""D:\temp\test.bat"" Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR", vbNormalFocus)
```

Also try the following to keep the cmd window open and see errors:

```
Call Shell("cmd /k ""C:\reporting\Release\Report_GenerationV_0.exe"" Alarm 1-1-1 00:00:00 1-1-1 00:00:00 DTPUN02-01\ADMINISTRATOR")
```

Comment: Thank you, while I havent fixed the issue yet, its definitely something to do with my exe file... replacing that with the batch file you created works...

Comment: @angadbector Try the `cmd /k` I suggested in my last code line. It should keep the cmd window open. If your exe is able to output errors you will be able to see them there. • Otherwise you would have to investigate the code of your exe file.

Comment: its a very very simple exe file so i didnt setup errors, but what i find really confusing is that if i pput a breakpoint in my VBA and copy paste the entire string and put it in "Run", it executes perfectly, however in CMD or Shell it doesnt...

Comment: @angadbector I have no idea how this can happen and what is different in using `Run`. The only thing I can say is that it should work according the information I gave above.

Comment: OK I figured it out, ended up having to manage errors in my code. I was referencing an image in my local directory (of the program) and when it was called from "RUN" it appears it used the program directory as the root folder, however when it was called from shell, the VBA directory was used as the root folder, TIL..... only cost me 2 days of my life....

Comment: Thank you  @Pᴇʜ, you are a life saver!! knowing that it was my .exe that was the issue put me on the right path, never again am I going to call files or deal with any I/O without a try catch anymore

Comment: @angadbector actually there is nothing worse than a silent error (without reporting/logging it). Ever a force close is better than a silent error (I think, because you at least realize something gone wrong). If an error occurs you need to know it. If it is silent everybody assumes that everything is correct (while it is actually not). So the worst errors are the ones that you cannot see. This is not limited to I/O but everything your code does btw.